# Setting up Identity in MVC core with AspNetUser and Role in already established database connected via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have an already complete ASP.NET Core MVC application that I am trying to add authentication to via ASP.NET Identity. I have a database with tables for `AspNetUsers` and `Roles` being used in other projects that I'd like to connect this project to using Entity Framework (the rest of this project uses dapper, but it seems entity is easier for authentication?).

I've been trying to piece together how to use Identity for authentication based on info in the already established database connected through Entity Framework, but I'm not sure my setup is right, and I keep running into errors. Are there better strategies for providing Authentication in an already complete ASP.NET Core MVC application from an already established database?

Here are some highlights of my setup and details on the latest error I've run into:

Entity Framework generated classes for `AspNetUser` and `Roles` that extend the `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` classes, respectively. A number of the  property names are the same as in the Identity classes, do I need to overwrite ?

I am running into an error in my `DbContext` class when I try to login.

Specifically at:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.RoleId)
                .HasName("PK_Role");

            entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleID");

            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(250)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.RoleName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });
```

`entity.HasKey` is throwing

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A key cannot be configured on 'Roles' because it is a derived type

Does this have something to do with `RoleId` being an int instead of string or not being named 'Id'?

Edit: the Role class:

```
public partial class AspNetRoles: IdentityRole
{
    override public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

I also am now getting the exception :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The indexes {'NormalizedName'} on 'IdentityRole' and {'Name'} on 'AspNetRoles' are both mapped to 'AspNetRoles.RoleNameIndex' but with different columns ({'NormalizedName'} and {'Name'}).'

Comment: How did you define the Role class?

Comment: @Rena I edited to include the class

Comment: Hi @bx ded,Your DbContext contains Roles class but you give a AspNetRoles class.Could you share the whole DbContext and model?